# hostapd: clients cannot connect

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, hostapd

I built a small Linux system based on Buildroot. I'd like to configure Buildroot and hostapd so that the machine works as a WPA2 access point. Unfortunately, my laptop (the client) cannot connect. hostapd is printing the following line and afterwards there is some silence (~5sec) until the client disconnects.

```
WPA: pairwise key handshake completed (RSN)
```

The linux system uses a wireless card with a Atheros AR5212 chip (with the ath5k driver)

hostapd.conf:

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ssid=meshtrix
channel=1
hw_mode=g
wpa=3
wpa_passphrase=mtmt123123
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
logger_syslog=-1
logger_syslog_level=2
logger_stdout=-1
logger_stdout_level=1
debug=0
dump_file=/tmp/hostapd.dump
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd
ctrl_interface_group=0
```

Does anyone has an idea why the client cannot connect successfully?

Answer (score 1):

Your hostapd is fine. I suspect your connected interface is not bridged to your wlan0, or you do not have a dhcpd running.

Options:

1. Install DHCP server(i.e. dnsmasq).
2. Bridge your wlan0 to ethx.

   brctl addbr br0

   brctl addif br0 ethx

then add to your hostapd.conf

```
bridge=br0
```